Coloring of Table Header
First: I've split up my question(s) from Cleaning up code and here is one of the bullets, with the code somewhat reduced.
Consider
\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt
]{article}

\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.3cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,array}

\def\mlr{1}
\newcommand*\saenk[1]{\raisebox{\fpeval{-5/9*\mlr}ex}{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{
    |p{5cm}|
     >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}|
     >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}|
  }
   \hline
      \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{\fpeval{-1.5*\mlr}ex}{Du kender \dots}}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\saenk{Du kan beregne \dots}} \\[\mlr ex]
   \cline{2-3}
    
    & \saenk{sider}
    & \saenk{vinkler} \\[\mlr ex]
   \hline
      A & B & C \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}

Question
How do I color the cell background of the header of the table, i.e., the cells with the text Du kender \dots, Du kan beregne \dots, sider and vinkler? That is (probably), how can I use colortbl with this code?

This question can be simplified further, now for example I could not run the code because I don't have texgyrepagella installed and I had to change the fonts, however the font is probably not relevant for the question so all the fontspec things can be removed to make it easier to reproduce. The same goes for all math, PSTricks drawings, etc.

Furthermore it was not fully clear to me what you mean with "color the header of the table", if you mean text color or cell background color. Assuming cell background color I tried the colortbl package, which is the standard way of coloring table cells/rows/columns - you have most likely also encountered this package when doing research for your question. However, when just loading the package (and not using any of its commands yet) I got a Misplaced \omit error. So I guess the question essentially is "how can I use colortbl with this code?" Maybe you can edit to reflect this.

@Marijn Thanks for the heads-up; I've edited my question.

Can you accept to use tabularray?

@Stephen Easily. :-) However, I would like to be able to achieve all three bullets in the referenced question at the top of the question.

With tabularray:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.3cm,
  vmargin = 3cm,showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tblr}{colspec={|Q[5cm]|Q[c,5cm]|Q[c,5cm]|}, rowspec={|Q[cyan6]|Q[cyan6]|Q|}}
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Du kender \dots & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Du kan beregne \dots & \\
  & sider & vinkler \\
  A & B & C \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}



With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  hmargin = 2.3cm,
  vmargin = 3cm,showframe
]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,ninecolors}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
\begin{NiceTabular}{w{l}{5cm}w{c}{5cm}w{c}{5cm}}[hvlines]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{cyan6}{1,2}
\Body
  \Block[c]{2-1}{Du kender \dots} & \Block{1-2}{Du kan beregne \dots} \\
  & sider & vinkler \\
  A & B & C \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}


